# Division in Haskell, Type class

Tags: haskell, division

I have a function which, taken two ints as paramters, should return the result of their division.

I am, however, unsure about a few things.

Firstly, what the return type would be? I.e., `4/2` would return `2`, therefore I presume an `Int`, but `5/3` ...? Also what is the best operator to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`div` is integer division in haskell.  It will round down like C would do.  So

```
4 `div` 2 = 2
5 `div` 3 = 1
```

To do regular division you have to convert to a `Fractional` type with `fromIntegral`.

```
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

So the `(/)` operator takes two `Fractional` types and returns the same fractional type.  Examples would be `Rational`, `Double`, and `Float`.

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm still relatively unsure, if I wanted a function "getDiv" which takes Ints x and y and parameters how should I structure it?

Comment: @DarioP,such a function already exists.  It's called `div`.  You can do `div 5 3` or `5 \`div\` 3`.  They mean the thing.  You can use `\`` around any function with (at least) two arguments to turn it into an infix function.  Just as you can do `5.3 / 2.4` or `(/) 5.3 2.4`

Comment: If you want regular division with a result of a `Fractional` type: `getDiv x y = fromIntegral x / fromIntegral y`. In that case, however, it is probably clearer to just use `fromIntegral` directly to convert the `Int` values, without bothering with a separate function.

Comment: "will round down like C would do" depends on your definition of "round down." `(-5) \`div\` 3` is `-2`, while in C, `(-5) / 3` is `-1`.

Comment: @kqr I guess i've never really done integer division on negative numbers

Comment: @DiegoNolan I don't blame you. How rounding behaves when it comes to negative numbers is one of those quirks you learn to look out for with time.

Comment: The quot function behaves like C.